# How to manage concretely with unamangeable model relationship in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, model, relationship, one-to-one, many-to-one

I was asked to use two sources of data sharing the same column and build both a many-to-one and one-to-one relationship with PowerBI. It  is not possible to modelize any of two relationship and therefore I was wondering on how to solve the problem and create a connection between them.

Could you please provide some examples, based on your experience?

Thanks

Comment: Can you rephrase your question as this: "It is not possible to fit them none of two" isn't clear. Provide some sample data and what you have tried.

Comment: I clarified what I mean. Just try to use any of the data souces you can apply this model on, whatever they are. I am still learning the usage of Power BI but what i did it is just upload table from websites, manage relationship using as key the same coulmns shared in both the datasets and then apply the two relationship. It is hard to me what actually I am supposed to do when it is said to solve the case of modeization AND make connection between the tables. I guess mine is a problem of terminology

Comment: Can you update your question with a snip of any error messages. Ate you able to create one relationship? It is not normal to create more than on relationship on the same columns.

Comment: This is exactly the aim of the task. I have to modify somehow the dataset to do model more than one relationship. Anyway, error are tipical messages  as to the cardinality